# What is this lazy sum notation supposed to mean?

Tags: notation, riemann-sum

I'm used to writing iterative summations like this:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^3 f(i)
$$

But I have a thermodynamics book that uses
$$
 \sum_s f(s)  
$$

And similar with no explanation.  The [Wikipedia article on the topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(statistical_mechanics)) uses the same notation as well, also without explanation.  Explanations of the Riemann sum all use my notation.  What gives?

Comment: If it's just $s$ with no restriction, it means that the sum is taken over all possible $s$

Comment: Neither of those looks like any Riemann sum I've seen. Riemann sums are finite sums, and are of the form $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i)\Delta x_i$$ where there are $n$ subintervals in the partition, $\Delta x_i$ is the length of the $i$th subinterval, and $x_i$ lies in the $i$th subinterval, right?

Comment: When someone writes something like $\sum_s f(s)$, the set of values that $s$ can take on is supposed to be clear from context. In the Wikipedia article, the context seems to tell us that there is one value of $s$ for each exact state that the system can occupy.

Comment: It's not a Riemann sum. It's just a sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered in the comments, $\displaystyle \sum_s \dots$ means a sum over all sensible values of $s$.  In the wikipedia article referenced in the question, $s$ represents a microstate of a system, so the sum is over all possible microstates $s$ of the system.

Other variations can be found on [the Wikipedia page on Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation), e.g.

- $\displaystyle \sum_{a\in A}\dots$ which sums over each elements $a$ in the set $A$
- $\displaystyle \sum_{d~|~n}\dots$ which sums over all divisors $d$ of the number $n$.